# What’s the difference between 「長」,「長い」and「長く」？

Tags: meaning

I’m trying to understand the difference between「長」,「長い」and「長く」

I believe they all mean “long”, but I’m not sure what context to use each one in.

Comment: First of all, you can look it up in a dictionary like Jisho. There, you will find a translation, and also what kind of word it is you're looking at. For example, you can see that [長 is a prefix/suffix](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%95%B7-2) while [長い is an I-adjective](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%95%B7%E3%81%84). I think downvotes here are mainly because your question could have been answered easily with just a bit of research. After looking it up, you can still ask a question stating what you found and what still confuses you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

長い is a form in the present tense as an adjective.

長く is an adverbial form.

長 is a stem (a part that doesn't change by infection) or a component/suffix for compound words like 面長{おもなが} or 足長｛あしなが｝.